# Wired network not working after suspend in 14.10

Tags: networking, suspend, 14.10

After upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 I have to manually restart the network-manager every time I wake my computer from sleep (RAM). Even then sometimes ot takes 10 or more seconds to get the eth0 interface up.

Everything was working perfectly with 14.04. I've tried both 3.13 and 3.16 kernels.

Only network related thing I can find from the system log is:

```
[ 3857.008083] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 3859.810431] ATL1E 0000:02:00.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up <1000 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 3859.810448] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

And this is after I've manually restarted the network-manager.

However, there are usually quite a lot systemd related error messages in my logs, for example:

```
[ 3792.339745] systemd-logind[1231]: Failed to start session scope session-c11.scope: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken. org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
```

Are these somehow related?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by creating a file `/etc/pm/sleep.d/15_network-manager`

with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
                sleep 5s
                service network-manager restart
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: Yes, this solution obviously works in a way, but it doesn't really "fix" anything. I mean, there is still a huge timeout before I can use the network after wakeup: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kvZNMTKG) Just look at those timestamps!

Answer (score 1):

I got this sorted out finally: My wired network started to behave normally when I switched from upstart to systemd ie. installed the systemd-sysv package.